# Kubernetes create private namespace/domain (FQDNs)

Tags: docker, dns, kubernetes, containers

I am migrating legacy product(VMs) to kubernetes. This product defines its services inside the product using FQDN style and makes heavy use of /etc/hosts files to simulate DNS and implement services resolution

```
#service names
service1.customer.domain.com
service2.customer.domain.com

# /etc/hosts
192.22.22.21 service1.customer.domain.com
192.22.22.22 service2.customer.domain.com
```

Changing this FQDN service naming style e.g. `servicename.a.b.c` would have significant impact on the product so I am trying to maintain this.I was looking to see how i could achieve this in Kubernetes. I hoped to use [Kubernetes Namespaces](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/) but they disallow FQDN style enforcing  a namespace with a single String with no dots while [Kubernetes Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) apply similar restrictions.

I might have to just bite the bullet and refactor it fully but I was wondering if there was a simpler way to replicate the service name/resolution behaviour in the legacy product in kubernetes?

We cannot control the root domain, this is defined by our customer e.g. `customer1.netwk5.workers.us.com`. We would use this to define things like cookie domain, generate SSL certs for web server, configure LDAP and so on

Comment: It's not addressed directly in the question, but to be clear- services in k8s automatically get in-cluster dns names of $servicename.$namespace.svc.cluster.local- can the product be configured to use names in that format? e.g. can you control the root domain and deploy the services into a namespace called "customer"?

Comment: hi @JonahBenton, we can't control root domain, it varies per customer & depends on their intranet. Usually provide us with URL for our UI e.g.. customer1.netwk5.workers.us.com, we then use this to set up cookie domain, SSL certs, configure user mgmt, LDAP domains and etc. We have 100s of config scripts initializing& wiring all this stack together. Essentially, I'm trying to shoe horn an old "deployment and config technology" into K8s with minimal s/w change. For the most part, I can, but this is one of the challenges.
We could change everything to suit k8s but this has knock on effect/cost

Comment: Yup, gotcha. So you need the equivalent of a DNS controller and configurable DNS server to ensure the names the product uses resolve to k8s resources. At first blush it should not be hard to produce such a thing using eg Consul and the Operator framework. Not out of the box, but pretty small engineering effort.

Comment: yep, exactly or something that simulates this... we already use Consul for some service discovery/registration in a different version of our product (on cloud). One option (i was avoiding) would be to introduce consul as you suggest but then we'd have two parallel service registration/lookup solutions in one product (consul and k8s). If I was to consider using Consul i think i'll just go all out and do it right and refactor fully for k8s extracting a lot of our config from scripts and .properties files to configmaps etc.. thank you for your replies

Comment: sure, sure- the thinking was that since consul can respond to dns, you could use consul instead of kube-dns for dns in the cluster, and add a controller to sync .svc records to domain.com records in consul. anyway, good luck!

Comment: thank you for all your comments/advice...